pyspark open pipe in udf function
Use the image from here to describe my question.

As above, the python UDF function is executed in the python process in worker node.
Before the Executor(JVM) process started, I created a pipe and write message to it, like below:
import os, sys

print ("-----------")

r, w = os.pipe()
os.write(w, b"Hello, world\n")
os.close(w)
os.environ["PIPE_READ_FD"] = str(r)

And after the Executor(JVM) process started, I try to get the read file descriptor and read message, this can work fine:
pipe_read_fd_str = os.environ.get("PIPE_READ_FD", "-1")
print("--------- pipe_read_fd_str=" + pipe_read_fd_str)

r = int(pipe_read_fd_str)

r = os.fdopen(r)
print("-------- Read text:", r.read())
r.close()

But if I do the same work in the UDF function which runs in the Python Process, I got

[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Questions:
Is the Python Process started by the Executor(JVM) process closed the read descriptor?
I checked the source code, not found a clue, can someone share some light on this?
